# Show popup when hover image

Tags: html, image, onmouseover

I want to show a popup when the user hovers the images.
As test, I want to show the String 'Test'. 
With this code, it don't show anything.

```
<td width='27' height='17' style='border:1px solid #99a1ba align:center'>
<img src='../images/mission_ampm.png' onMouseOver='test' onClick=\"window.open('availability.jsp? user="+person.getPersonID()+"&clickeddate="+dateFormat.format(today2.getTime())+"','_self')\" /></td>
```

Comment: `onMouseOver="alert('test');"` should give you a hint

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to alert something, you have to write this :

```
onmouseover="alert('test');"
```

If you want a "tooltip", you can use the `title` attribute :

```
title="test"
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to show a sort of baloon above the image with the content of that image. An alertbox is too big, it must be something small.